# Is there any way to know how long it took a dts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dts

After the execution of a "dts" is there some way to know how long it took to execute it?

Comment: Do you mean in SSISDB? Check the execution logs?

Comment: That's already logged and displayed in the package's execution history. Right click on the package, `Reports > Standard Reports > All Executions`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i cant find that option.
check the img please. https://imgur.com/a/Ps07rPZ

Comment: Right click on the *package*, not the database